# Replacing characters in a char*

Tags: c++

How would one go to replace characters in a char*?

For example:

```
int main() {
    char* hello = "hello";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        hello[i] = 'a';
    }
   cout << hello;
}
```

No output at all. Just pauses on me and says that the program isn't responding.

Expected output: `aaaaa`

Comment: If you turn on compiler warnings it should be able to detect bugs like this (and many others).

Comment: You can't replace characters in a `char*`; you can replace characters in an **array** of `char`. A `char*` is usually a **pointer** to the first element of an array of `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a pointer to a string literal, and string literals in C++ are *constant* arrays of characters. Attempting to modify constant data leads to *undefined behavior*.

You can solve this by making `hello` an array:

```
char hello[] = "hello";
```

Answer (score 2):

`char* hello = "hello";` should be `char hello[] = "hello";`

The former is a string literal which you are not allowed to change. The latter is an array from which you can change any character in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

> char* hello = "hello";

Actually this is a string literal, and linker stores this "hello" string  on a separate memory section of the program called Read Only memory area (check the linker generated memory map file (possibly .map extension) to see the program memory map).

> char* hello

hello is a pointer variable and it will be stored on the stack area of the program.

Now pointer variable *hello* keeps the address of the read only memory (base address of the string literals).

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hello[i] = 'a';
}
```

You are trying to modify Read Only memory, In such case it depends on the OS what exception it generates (In some cases you will find segmentation fault also).

**Solution:**

Define the array on stack(Local to the function) or data memory(Global).

```
char hello[] = "hello";
```

For above convention linker will map the string "hello" on the stack (Local to the function) or data memory(Global).

**Recommendation**
Use keyword *const* if using string literals to avoid accidental modification of Read only memory, By defining *const* compiler will throw a indication if any part of the code is trying to modify the read only area.

```
const char* hello = "hello";
```

Read below.

> From the C99 standard 6.4.5/5 "String Literals - Semantics":
>
> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals. The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the
>   array elements have type  char, and are initialized with the
>   individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence; for wide string
>   literals, the array elements have type wchar_t, and are initialized
>   with the sequence of wide characters...
>
> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**